# Tomcat change javascript file no need to restart server

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat

Every time I make a change to a javascript file in my war/ directory I need to restart tomcat to be able to see a change.  Is there a way to just reload the page without the need to restart tomcat for non-java code changes (JS/CSS/HTML/images)?  I looked into the context.xml and doing:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

However, that didn't help.  If I would need to set a WatchedResource, it would be all files in my war/assets/ directory.  I'm not using Eclipse or an IDE and I'm on a Mac. Is there anyway to setup tomcat so I don't need to restart after every non-java code change?

Comment: How about just **reloading** the page? You know, like F5 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you made a change in javascript page there is no need to restart the server.Whenever you modify any thing which needa\s to compile then only you need to restart after recompilation.

Comment: Odd, I'm not seeing any change for javascript files. I can add and remove alert(1); and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

there is a possibility to do something called AUTODEPLOYMENT so whenever you save your new changes the console will instantly inform you with a message: autodeployment successfull. Note that if  you change something that needs compilation then rebuilding must be executed first.